# Sql game zone Query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Consider a gamezone having two tables : Table1 and Table2

In Table1, the data gets entered whenever you enter in a gamezone:

Table1

---

```
*user_Id* : integer type  <br>
*Time_of_entry* : timestamp type
```

In Table2 data gets entered only when the user makes a transaction  (spends or gains money) and it consists of the following fields :

Table2

---

```
*user_Id* :  integer type      <br>      
*Time_of_transaction* : timestamp type <br>  
*Money* : integer
```

You need to find out the last MONEY of each day for each different user and if there is no transaction on a particular day (that is, there is no data in Table2 for a particular day and user but there is an entry in Table1 - i.e. user entered in gamezone but did not spend money) then consider the previous day money as his money for the day.

How would I perform this kind of query?

sample tables has been attached as image  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iMuo.png)

Comment: `mysql` and `oracle` are different **RDBMS** products.

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of your question, which is currently hard to read?

Comment: done... @tim Biegeleisen

Comment: @ShaktiKumar - Please recreate table1 and table2 with some data and your output based on that. It would be better if you use [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to create tables. Without some example, it would be very difficult to visualize your problem.

Answer (score 0):

With this SELECT you will get, for each user in Table1, the last entry on Table2 for that user, and if there is no entry, a 0 as Money value.

```
SELECT 
    T1.user_Id,
    T3.Time_of_Transaction,
    ISNULL(t3.Money,0) as Money
FROM Table1 as T1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        T2.user_Id,
        T2.Time_of_Transaction,
        T2.Money
    FROM Table2 as T2
    WHERE T2.Time_of_Transaction=(
        SELECT MAX(Time_of_Transaction)
        FROM Table2
        WHERE user_Id=T2.user_Id
    )
) as T3 ON T1.user_id=T3.user_id
```

It can be perfected, but it should work.

**EDIT:** To obtain an entry for each day and, in case of not having transactions for a given day get the last momeny transaction the approach should be more like this:

```
SELECT
    user_Id,
    Time_of_entry,
    (
        -- Get the last money transaction of the user according to his last login
        SELECT Money
        FROM Table2 as T2
        WHERE user_Id=T1.user_Id 
        AND Time_of_Transaction= (
            -- Get the last date with a money transacion according to his last login
            SELECT MAX(Time_of_Transaction)
            FROM Table2
            WHERE user_Id=T2.user_Id
            -- This has to be adjusted to filter the Time_of_Transaction according to the date and not hour.
            AND CAST(Time_of_Transaction as Date)<=CAST(T1.Time_of_entry as Date)
        )
    ) as Money
FROM Table1 as T1
```

Comment: @Doliveras...What is T3 in this solution??

Comment: @ShaktiKumar T3 is the alias of the subselect used in the LEFT JOIN. The select enclosed in () after the LEFT JOIN

Comment: @Doliveras..My question was...to get the last money of each user for each day and if he did not expends any money  on a particular day then consider previous money as his last money

Comment: @ShaktiKumar My bad. I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @Doliveras..no problem. :)..can you help me with this?